# Which driver should I use with a 9600 GT Mobile?

Tags: drivers, nvidia, hardware, gpu, proprietary

I checked the Additional Drivers offered for my card and I saw four options:

- NVIDIA accelerated graphics drivers (version 173)
- NVIDIA accelerated graphics drivers (post-release updates) (version 173-updates)
- NVIDIA accelerated graphics drivers (version current) (Recommended)
- NVIDIA accelerated graphics drivers (post-release updates)(version current-updates)

I'm not sure which one to pick. I want a driver that's stable but also takes advantage of my card's hardware.

Comment: Use the recommended one.

Answer (score 0):

Use the recommended one is my advice. I'd say use the open source one but that wouldn't get all of your card's power.

I'm running on a Quadro 320m which is 8600GT based and the proprietary driver gave me excessive static which is still persistent after switching to the open source driver. Just a word of warning.